# twitter api not working with foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, api, twitter, foreach

I cannot get the foreach loop to display any data from the twitter api

Please see code below. However, it does display data on print_r array.

thank you for your time in advance

```
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);
     require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

 /** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
  $settings = array(
      'oauth_access_token' => "*******",
       'oauth_access_token_secret' => "*******",
       'consumer_key' => "********",
       'consumer_secret' => "*******"
      );


       /** Perform a GET request and echo the response **/
       /** Note: Set the GET field BEFORE calling buildOauth(); **/
       $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
        $getfield = '?q=love+you&count=20';
        $requestMethod = 'GET';
        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        $string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
         ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
        if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there 
          was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error 
       message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."
       </em></p>";exit();}


    foreach($string as $tweets) {

      echo $tweets['name'] . '<br />';

    }

    cannot get the foreach loop to display any data from the twitter api
```

Please see code below. However, it does display data on print_r array.

thank you for your time in advance

```
 /**here is the a sample of the array data but when the foreach loop is 
 added the screen is blank no error is dispayed no data is displayed**/ 

Array
(
    [statuses] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [metadata] => Array
                    (
                        [iso_language_code] => en
                        [result_type] => recent
                    )

                [created_at] => Thu Mar 05 23:16:36 +0000 2015
                [id] => 573623174589472768
                [id_str] => 573623174589472768
                [text] => @TheVampsband #TheVampsVIP Please choose me and 
    @Charlotte_94x to winShe hit tweet limitWe love you so much! We
     beg89
                [source] => Twitter for iPhone
```

Comment: If this code display something in `print_r()`, then attach some sample. Btw, in your `json_decode()` function, change second paramater to just `TRUE` instead of `$assoc = TRUE`. It's OK, but not necessary.

Comment: ok attached a little sample but the array displays all the data from a user

Comment: There is missing start of the `print_r()` which is more important to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all you loop over wrong array. Array you looking for is under `statuses` index, so change your loop into:

```
foreach($string['statuses'] as $tweets) {
    echo $tweets['name'] . '<br />';
}
```

Look at your `print_r()` and check carefully how sub array are build. E.g. if you want to print name of each tweet author, you should modify yor echo in foreach to:

```
echo $tweets['user']['name'] . '<br />';
```

because output array has structure

```
array(..., 'user' => array('name' => 'Example name', ...));
```

Comment: Analyze your output array carefully. Each subarray need to be accessed by index to get its value.